# Python remove gibberish and everything after from a string

Tags: python, string

Just wondering if there is a way to cut all the gibberish from a string. (for example, if the string was: `stackoverflowfoajfasjsdksakklsslQuestion`) How would I remove the gibberish and anything after?

The reason I am asking for this is that I have a camera that only saves things as: `"Image01jsjajdiahdkasdiajdksjCameraImage"` (stuff like that) and I want to remove all the stuff after the image number. It would be good if this worked with any file name, too.

Comment: Define gibberish ...

Comment: sure. Write code that identifies gibberisch. use str.replace or regex.sub or any other means you can think of to remove identified gibberish.

Comment: Can you share your code so far?

Comment: What is the rule that tells you where the gibberish starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string you want is fixed length, you can get the first characters as a new string.

```
#This is the full string with gibberish
fullString = 'StackOverflow1235125'

#We'd like to get StackOverflow
getString = 'StackOverflow'

#We need the length
getStringLength = getString.__len__() #This returns 13 because StackOverflow is 13 chars.

returnString = fullString[:getStringLength] #This trims the fullString, only leaving the first 13 characters.
print(returnString)
```

The output is

```
StackOverflow
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I have a few other cameras, but thankfully they all save the same way! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

*I want to remove all the stuff after the image number*

```py
import re

text = "Image01jsjajdiahdkasdiajdksjCameraImage"

result = re.match(r"(.*\d+)", text)

print(result.group())
```

Output:

```
Image01
```